# How to remove version from the extent report

Tags: selenium, extent

I am using the extent report in my selenium project ,i want to remove the version showing in the right corner of the report.

can any one help me on this.[image]

Comment: Off-topic here. Why do you want to remove that version? Are you ready to spend days of work for that? What did you try? Did you download and study the source code of selenium?

Comment: how can you say its off topic ,i am customizing according to my requirement.

Comment: Because it is not a programming question.

Comment: stack over flow is not only for programming questions.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a `extent-config.xml` file?

Find in there something that looks like this:

```
   <styles>
      <![CDATA[

      ]]>
    </styles>
```

And add your custom css. You'll have to inspect the element you want to hide, to find a selector for it. And then you can add css, something like this:

```
   <styles>
      <![CDATA[
        #id-of-the-element{display:none};
      ]]>
    </styles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

You will find something like this in `extent-config.xml`

```
 <scripts>
        <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function() {

            });
        ]]>
    </scripts>
```

Simply make this change:

```
<scripts>
        <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("class name")[1].remove()
            });
        ]]>
    </scripts>
```